# When testing a deck, what % of rejected hands is acceptable?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Good deck construction minimizes luck. I am about to enter my first tournament (Pauper). In addition to testing my deck against other decks in actual games, I simulate initial hands and first few cards using deckbox.org to help to fine tune it.

It is clear from simulation that I would have to mulligan at least a quarter of my hands. I would assume that beyond a certain mulligan percentage, a deck cannot possibly be competitive in a Pauper tournament.

While there may be special cases where a mulligan does not confer much of a disadvantage, let's assume for the purpose of this question that this deck is average in the sense that each time the initial hand is decreased by a card, it hurts chances of winning quite a bit.

Beyond what percentage of hands requiring mulligan would a deck be considered non-competitive? If someone has actually studied this question statistically, please provide a link to the study.

Comment: I don't think this quite answers your question, but it's a bunch of useful detail-oriented math: http://www.channelfireball.com/articles/in-development-a-mulligan-is-worth-three-cards/

Comment: My thoughts are that this question will have to be answered experimentally instead of mathematically. On that note, I asked [another related question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/23698/6692). Hopefully the answer to that one will provide a basis for answering this one.

Comment: @Rainbolt I agree that tabulating the info from tournaments would asking the question. I hope your question gets answered and that mulligan data is included. Though a completely different game, I recorded data for the game Cosmic Encounter when I was a teenager and was able to answer the question, "Which powers are best" with real data. This MTG question is answerable if someone has collected data.

Comment: On the other hand, it does depend on the deck: a deck that mulligans more often than average isn't necessarily worse. So while tournament data (restricted to top N places to avoid bad players/bad decks?) might get you a general idea, it's definitely helpful to have answers that think through some things as well.

Comment: As stated, I think this question is too broad - it depends too much on many different variables, including the power of individual cards, the power of cards in conjunction with other cards, how that changes with matchups, etc.

Comment: @HaoYe If we interpret it as "how often do people typically mulligan?" I think it's a fair question - yes, it depends, but perhaps we could say things like "pretty much all decks mulligan at least X% of the time, some mulligan a lot, Y% of the time". It doesn't really answer the question of "is this deck okay?" but really, that's not a question about mulligan rate - that's a question about win rate.

Comment: I think that deck's strategy is what matters here. Is card advantage important for your deck? Control decks usually suffer mulligans more because they need card advantage to avoid opponents threats.Other decks, like Dredge in Vintage or Trinisphere/Blood Moon decks want to cast a bomb as soon as possible. For these decks doing mulligan to 5 or even 4 cards looking for a bomb is ok.

Comment: For the purposes of this question, I'd like to know what typical mulligan rates are when special cases are removed. I think of decks trying to fill a graveyard and then using graveyard as an extended hand as being a special case where mulligans don't matter so much.

Comment: FWIW I lost all 6 games of my first pauper tournament (3 players). 2 out of 6 games had Mulligan issues. 2 out of 6 I was evenly matched and barely lost. Other 2 I faced a deck type I had never seen before and played badly through ignorance. I don't think it matters for this question but the deck was a blue/white heroic/control deck. I may be able to make it competitive with a little less heroic, a little more control, and cheap card manipulation to overcome my mulligan issues. If I had a benchmark for mulligan rates  (20% ??) that would help in refining the deck.

Comment: In my first pauper tournament I saw cards I had never heard of that did a great job of reducing the mulligan factor thanks to card manipulation: Ponder, Brainstorm, Gitaxian Probe, Preordain, and Gush. That player was able to mulligan a lot because he could rebuild his hand with these cards and arrange for his turn 4 kill with Kiln Fiend or Nivix Cyclops. This was the player that wiped me out because I was unaware of this strategy.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the format, your deck, and the current meta.
It also depends on why you're mulliganing:

- If you need to mulligan due to land percentage (too many/few), you need to fix your deck.
- If you need to mulligan because you have no creatures, it might be an issue, but that depends on how much you need them [Which in turn depends on what kind of deck your opponent is running]
- If you need to mulligan because you don't have a certain card in hand... How important is that card?  [It's probably OK to mulligan for a one-drop Enchantment* or a Layline (Which aren't pauper-legal), as long as it's worth losing the Card Advantage]

The best way to test it is to just build the deck, and see what happens.

*I have one Modern deck that sometimes has to mulligan down to three or two cards in hand.
As long as I'm not up against an aggro deck, I can still win with an opening hand of [Island, Quest for Ula's Temple].