# Where can I find raw data for DCI sanctioned Constructed tournaments?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

It is often easier to answer questions about Magic experimentally instead of mathematically. Anyone can see the final standing of a deck in a tournament and find out who piloted it. [Here is an example.](https://old.starcitygames.com/decks/results/formats_all/All/start_date/27-03-2015/end_date/29-03-2015/city/Richmond/w_perc/0/g_perc/0/r_perc/0/b_perc/0/u_perc/0/a_perc/0/order_1/finish/limit/25/start_num/0/) However, there is some data I cannot find:

- Mulligans taken
- Games played
- Games on the play
- Final life totals per game

Does this data exist for DCI sanctioned Constructed tournaments? If so, where can I find it?

MTGGoldfish has information, but they only appear to cover Limited formats. [Here is their page](http://www.mtggoldfish.com/limited/analysis/draft/ktk_ktk_ktk) covering Khans of Tarkir.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think most of this data exists. For paper tournaments the only one of these stats that gets recorded is games played, and they might track all of these for MTGO I haven't been able to find a source that lists any of them.

Comment: @diego "This data does not exist." is a valid answer. "If it exists, I cannot find it." would be another valid answer.

Comment: I may get around to that later, when I have more time to look into data from MTGO. Right now I'm not sure enough to write an answer saying the data doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of offline (non-MTGO) information, the only data point that is brought away from a tournament match is the match record - mulligans, die-roll winners, and life totals are not processed in any way.

There are not any resources online with general match records (i.e. how often matches end 2-0, etc.) that I am aware of. You can go into the archives of GPs and parse the information from the round results pages if you wanted to, but that's likely about it. I'm confident WotC has the capability to derive this type of information internally, but the data for more global audiences to derive it is not public. (nor would WotC likely make such data public)

The site you linked gets it's information by monitoring Magic Online and recording metadata based on games played there - there's definitely more data there, but you'd need to keep in mind that MTGO and paper Magic may have different results for different events, especially when you take into account the difference in draw procedures, and the occasional prevalence of decks in paper Magic which cannot be effectively piloted on MTGO. (or vice versa)

Comment: Why is WotC unlikely publicize the raw tournament data? How are the draw procedures for MTGO different from paper magic?

Comment: The later is simpler to answer - on MTGO, matches cannot end in a draw; one player's clock expires, and they lose the match. Intentional Draws also are not an option online.

The former is based on the nature of how WotC has worked with this data in the past. They have discouraged/prevented 3rd parties from working with tournament data directly in the past, and likely liability reasons preventing full tournament data accessibility. (imagine WotC getting in the middle of a custody case because tournament data indicated a kid as having played in certain events)

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot. By "draw procedures", I thought you meant drawing *cards*.